# Maven un-ban a dependency (in order to use a library)?

Tags: java, maven

We have a bill of material for all our projects that banned a certain dependency in the parent pom.xml. Now we need to use another library that uses that dependency. I can make an exclusion to exclude that banned dependency to compile. However, that makes the library throw a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Given that we do not want to remove the ban in the parent pom, is there a way that I can bring it in for just the library?

Comment: I'm guessing the bom uses the enforcer plugin? If so, you could deactivate that for your project using the property [`enforcer.skip`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html#skip)

Comment: Why is it banned? You don't want it on the classpath for technical reasons?  legal reasons?  Do you just not want developers using that library, or you don't want it on the classpath?

Comment: @sceaj I don't know exactly why it is banned. It's legacy code that touches many projects.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd you are correct. The bom uses the enforcer plugin.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I can compile if I add the `-Denforcer.skip=true` to `mvn clean install`. However, it would be nice if I can put that in the pom (then I don't have to add the option every time I compile it).

Comment: @breezymri added an answer for reference to show how it can be done in the pom. But agree that the accepted answer is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordind to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) you could use `includes` for that:

> includes - a list of artifacts to include. These are exceptions to the excludes. It is meant to allow wide exclusion rules with wildcards and fine tune using includes. If nothing has been excluded, then the includes have no effect. In otherwords, includes only subtract from artifacts that matched an exclude rule.
>   For example, to ban all xerces except xerces-api you would exclude "xerces" (groupId) and include "xerces:xerces-api"

Comment: In my project pom.xml, I added `incldues` to include that dependency. However when I do `mvn clean install`, I still get `Rule 3: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedDependencies failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: <dependency>`

Comment: Are you using the same `<id>` as is being used in parent pom?

Comment: @"Marcin Pietraszek" One question, with this solution using `includes`, I still get to retain all the other rules that was present in the parent bom, correct?

Comment: You're not changing your parent pom so those rules are intact. You're just adding an include that have effect on your "sub project" - you're just changing "effective pom" for it.

Comment: I saw something strange. So I just flat copied the parent bom part for the maven enforcer plugin and removed the one banned dependency. Then I could compile with no errors. If the child plugin section mearly modify the parent section with the same id, shouldn't the ban from parent pom still be included and cause a problem?

Comment: As I said above. Think of it as merge of parent and your pom. Common id is required to have that merge being done properly. You don't need to copy whole section, adding `includes` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip execution of the enforcer plugin via the pom.xml in 2 ways:

1. Through a property:

   ```
   <properties>
       <enforcer.skip>true</enforcer.skip>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Through plugin configuration

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <skip>true</skip>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```